# How does Gradle handle dependency conflict in multi module project

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I read in the gradle documentation that dependency conflict resolution is by default done so that gradle chooses the latest version of a lib.
I noticed that in a simple project that seems to work fine. Although in a multi modules project it seems that each module resolves its dependencies separately.

Example:

```
- Module-A:
  Dependency-C -> Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version1
  Dependency-D -> Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version2  <<<< this one is chosen for the module
- Module-B:
  Dependency-E -> Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version1
  Dependency-F -> Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version3  <<<< this one is chosen for the module
```

But in the end it will add both to the classpath, `Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version3` and `Transitive-Dependency-Y-Version2`

Why is that so? Is there a way to tell gradle to use only one version of each transitive dependency type for the whole project (without the need to force one by one)?

Comment: The dependency "Y-version-2" will be in the dependency set for module A, and "Y-version-3" is included in the the dependency set for module-B. Module A and module B have distinct dependency sets. If another module, say module G, depends on both module A and module B, then Y-version-3 will "win" over Y-version-2, in the dependency set for module G.

Comment: That was my theory, but that is not what is happening in my project. I will try to reproduce in some test project

Comment: I could not reproduce it. Trying in a demo project it works fine. My guess is that because my original project is too big, and has too many levels of transitive dependency nesting, gradle somehow cannot resolve it properly and ends up duplicating dependencies in the classpath.